# How to have different playback speed for different segments (location not time : nw vs se part of the frame) of video with openCv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, cpu-architecture

I have a video of myself driving with my hands on the wheel and street view from the street. I'd like to speed up the frame rate for only the street frames seen through the window! Any ideas?
This is basically playing two different videos in one, but I am not adding new video source , I just want to have different playback speed and end the video when the faster one is done.

This is my first question here on stack overflow! So sorry if I didn't adhere to all the guidelines.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
This is a lot like green screen in the movies, where they are in the car in the studio and add street footage later.

Let's say there are two separate flames, I want to increase play speed of only one while the other has normal playback speed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can edit your question if you want to add further clarification (instead of the comments).

Comment: Thnx @Timus, will do